# Signal strength ios 7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, core-telephony

Does somebody know which unit the following function gives me back?!

```
int CTGetSignalStrength();
```

This function linked with the coreTelephony Framework...I know that's a private one, but I just wanna know which unit I am getting back...

Comment: Signal strength is measured in dB, so it is quite possibly that. Can you give us an example output to verify it? If it's a negative number then it is most likely dB.

Comment: I don't think it is dBm cause if I open the Field Test Mode from Apple it gives me a value of -83 and the coreTelephony function gives 43...But I am not sure if the field Test Value is in dBm though

Comment: Well a couple ideas come to mind. Signal strength can change quick, though that's a fairly large change. It is also possible that Apple changed it (as it is a private method) and it ranks the signal on a scale from 0-100? Just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more [digging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427507/how-to-find-out-carrier-signal-strength-programatically), I can confirm it is the reading in dB, however it is negated. In other words, if the signal strength is -60dB, `CTGetSignalStrength()` will return 60.

To clarify more, the higher the number, the worse the signal.